# Keyboard height observer gives inacurate height

Tags: swift

I'm using the observer below to determine my keyboard height.
I then use this **keyboardHeight** to adjust the bottom constraint for a UIView (image attached):

```
@IBOutlet weak var postViewBottomContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}
```

and the method:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        print("Keyboard Height is:",keyboardHeight)
    }
}
```

, and here is where I change the height:

```
func startEditing() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.postViewBottomContraint.constant = self.keyboardHeight
        print ("Bottom constraint is:",self.postViewBottomContraint.constant.description)
        self.postTextView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

It adds a space between the keyboard and the UIView even though the **keyboardHeight** and the **bottomConstraint** are identical (in my case it is 253.0), is it adding something extra that is not visible or is there something else going on?

[image]

Comment: Please show the relevant code where you increase the height of the view.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri , done

Comment: I don't get how you even got the view to move up with that code. You are moving the view downwards by adding a constant. When you want to move the view up you should be subtracting the constant. Can you show the code where you set that view up and stored the constraint in the variable?

Comment: I am using the bottom constraint which is a NSLayoutConstraint and is 0 before the keyboard and 253 when keyboard launches? - @IBOutlet weak var postViewBottomContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

Comment: Can you edit that code also into the question?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using -253 instead of 253 to move it up?

Comment: No, that moves my constraint to below the keyboard and my view below the screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178063/discussion-between-rakesha-shastri-and-brewski).

Comment: Can you double check which constraint you have hooked to `postViewBottomConstraint` ?

Comment: Yeah, I double checked, I even deleted all other constraints to make sure there were not some runtime conflict that Xcode does not pick up, for now I just made it keyboardHeight -(minus) 50, till someone else comes up with the same problem :(

Comment: Can you share your storyboard constraints? Might have something to do with where you bottomAnchor is attached to.